# How set checked items in Ext.selection.CheckboxModel after render?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, checked

I'm using `Ext.selection.CheckboxModel` in `Ext.grid.Panel` and whant checked some items after data was binding and component is redering. The part of component that works without errors but wrong is below:

```
    listeners: {
        afterRender: function (thisObj, eOpts) {
            var window = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#' + 'requestOperator_kbkAccess-window')[0];
            if (window) {
                var row = window.accessGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0],
                    ppp = row.get('Ppp'),
                    codes = ppp.map(a => a.Code);

                Ext.defer(function () {
                    var selections = [];
                    codes.forEach(function (item, index) {
                        let i = thisObj.getStore().find('Code', item);
                        if (i !== -1) {
                            selections.push(store.getAt(i))
                        }
                    });

                    console.log(thisObj.getStore().data);

                    thisObj.getSelectionModel().select(selections);
                }, 100);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code receive string of codes like `022,077,009` from parent component and attempt set as checked this codes in `Ext.selection.CheckboxModel`. The wrong work of this code is that line `let i = thisObj.getStore().find('Code', item);` return -1 and in debug count of items in the `thisObj.getStore().data` is 0. But in console i see that `console.log(thisObj.getStore().data);` return expected result:
[image] 
On `viewready` result is same.

I'm new in extJs and don't understand what i'm doing wrong in that simple functionality? Please, help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this function after store get loaded :(https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#event-load)

You can do it like:

```
    listeners: {
        afterRender: function (thisObj, eOpts) {
            thisObj.getStore().on('load', function () {
                var window = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#' + 'requestOperator_kbkAccess-window')[0];
                if (window) {
                    var row = window.accessGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0],
                        ppp = row.get('Ppp'),
                        codes = ppp.map(a => a.Code);

                    Ext.defer(function () {
                        var selections = [];
                        codes.forEach(function (item, index) {
                            let i = thisObj.getStore().find('Code', item);
                            if (i !== -1) {
                                selections.push(store.getAt(i))
                            }
                        });

                        console.log(thisObj.getStore().data);

                        thisObj.getSelectionModel().select(selections);
                    }, 100);
                }
            });
        }
    },
```